# Как в ansible получить путь к файлу текущего плейбука?

Tags: linux, debian, ansible, ansible-playbook

Как в ansible получить путь к файлу текущего плейбука?

Допустим, я запускаю плейбук такой командой:

```sh
ansible-playbook example-playbook.yml
```

При этом текущая директория это `/home/user`.

Как внутри плейбука получить путь к файлу этого плейбука, т.е. `/home/user/example-playbook.yml`?

В официальной документации не нашел решения.

Answer (score 1):

Есть пачка специальных переменных, которая содержит подобную инфу. Называется "[Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)", гуглится по `ansible magic vars`. Конкретно тебе нужна переменная `playbook_dir`:

```yaml
- name: Get dir location
  debug:
    msg: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
```

С именем плейбука сложнее, возможно надо будет шаманить с `basename`.